# Core Plot 1.0: Provide Custom Labels for Legends

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, core-plot

I am using **CorePlot** 1.0 and would like to add a **legend** to my **bar chart** (which is a subclassed XYGraph). I have the datasource and legend title methods in the viewController, which instantiates the bar chart and sets itself as its delegate.

***I have spend quite a few hours with different delegate and legend setups but can't find my error. Can you give my any hints on where I may have made an error?***

I have subclassed XYGraph to generate bar charts as follows:

**`.h`**

```
@interface BarLineChart : CPTXYGraph
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <CPTPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In my implementation **.m**, I set up the legend as follows:

```
 // Add legend
CPTLegend *legend           = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:self];
legend.fill                 = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.15]];
legend.borderLineStyle      = axisLineStyle;
legend.cornerRadius         = 10.0;
legend.swatchSize           = CGSizeMake(16.0, 16.0);
CPTMutableTextStyle *legendTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
legendTextStyle.color       = [CPTColor whiteColor];
legendTextStyle.fontSize    = 10.0;
legend.textStyle            = legendTextStyle;
legend.rowMargin            = 1.0;
legend.numberOfRows         = 3;
legend.paddingLeft          = 10.0;
legend.paddingTop           = 10.0;
legend.paddingRight         = 10.0;
legend.paddingBottom        = 10.0;
legend.delegate = self.delegate;

self.legend                 = legend;
self.legendAnchor           = CPTRectAnchorTop;
self.defaultPlotSpace.delegate = self.delegate;
```

I keep the datasource methods in a separate viewController, for which  I have set the delegate (stored in self.delegate). 
This is my viewController's interface:

```
`@interface FinstatViewController : CompanyViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, CompanyPresenter, ChartSelectionDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate, CPTLegendDelegate, CPTScatterPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate>`
```

My data source methods to get the plot data works fine, but the legend title method

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

is never called.

Comment: Did you get any solutions on this? I have a similar issue as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend title method is part of the datasource, not the delegate. If your datasource and delegate are in different classes, make sure the title method is implemented in the correct one.

Comment: Eric, I have implemented the title method in my view controller, where I have implemented the data source method. I have verified my delegates `CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate, CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate, CPTLegendDelegate` using the debugger and they seem to be set correctly. Did I miss a delegate? THANK YOU!

Comment: The method `barFillForBarPlot` which uses the same delegate is called correctly.  THANK YOU!