# Core Plot legendTitleForBarPlot will never be called (bug?)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

Instead of getting the plot identifiers as the legends labels, I would to provide custom text. My plot identifiers are not suitable as a label, for example "#OpMarg", which I would like to replace with "operating margin"

I have implemented the methods

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

and

```
-(BOOL)legend:(CPTLegend *)legend shouldDrawSwatchAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index forPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot inRect:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context;
```

However, `legendTitleForBarPlot` is never called.

What is the error in my implementation?

How can I override the basic legend labels and provide my custom text for each label?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Plot 1.0: Provide Custom Labels for Legends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720863/core-plot-1-0-provide-custom-labels-for-legends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

the ' seem somewhat wrong =)
just a wild guess.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, the ' were present in my question due to bad formatting only (please apologize the typo). In my code, the ' were not present however.